# Direct flashplayer to flashplayer video streaming through webcam

Tags: flash, video, streaming

I would like to know if it's possible for flash to stream it's webcam directly to another computer without a flash media server in the middle, I want to build a highly scalable video system which basically logs people into the site, records their ip address and then when someone wants to chat to that person, connect the output from the webcam to the input of the flash video player and vice versa.

the idea being that they basically plug together, rather than a huge, expensive, bandwidth hungry server in the middle.

is it possible? I heard that flash can talk binary directly to sockets now, could this be a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, this is possible, using adobe stratus. check out  the project homepage: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/

the resources provided should actually suffice ... the sample app should get your started really well ...

Answer (score 0):

I was going through my old questions, what I really need is this:

http://code.google.com/p/haxevideo/

the stratus idea is ok, but unfortunately leaves me critically exposed to adobe just turning it off, or revoking my key, I prefer a technology which leaves me in control.

however, I'm going to accept the above answer, since it was the first and still is correct.